# reading problem from socket during run time

Tags: c++, symbian

i am able to read data during debug time ,but when i perform write and read ,during run time ,i am unable to read data during run time

```
IssueRead()
{

    delete iBuffer1;

    iBuffer1 = NULL;

    iBuffer1 = HBufC8::NewL(1000);

    TPtr8 bufferPtr2(iBuffer1->Des());  


    iEchoSocket->Recv(bufferPtr2,0,iStatus,iLength);    

    //iEchoSocket->RecvOneOrMore(bufferPtr2,0,iStatus,iLength);


    SetActive();

}
```

i am using three active object for connect,read and write

Answer (score 2):

bufferPtr2 goes out of scope after SetActive, it needs to live until RunL is called.
Common Symbian descriptor misstake.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the problem was during the run time. I guess that did you check out the socket connection as well as a handshake protocol before the communication is established ?  you were using the three active objects for communications, did you synchronize those objects during reading/writing ?

I hope it helps.

Tiger.

Comment: yes
i have made symchronisation properly
even it is reading data properly during debug time